# Thoughts about H bridge

Tags: pwm, bjt, h-bridge, npn, fet

I'm planning to build a pwm driven H bridge. I have all set up, flyback diodes, pull up and down resistors on high and low on bridge's side, decoupling capacitors and so on, but I only have [TIP122 Darlington BJT](https://www.adafruit.com/datasheets/TIP120.pdf) available at my university. I know I need a big base current to charge base capacitance as fast as possible to allow faster PWM frequencies. Unlike some [FET's](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/IR/IRF840B.pdf), it doesn't have "fast switching" written on its datasheet. But besides that, the datasheet lacks the "ON base input resistance" and the input capacitance, only output capacitance.

How can I say for sure that this BJT doesn't suits me? I'm planning using 100Hz for pwm

Comment: for 100hz suits well, but is a 100hz enough?

Comment: this is my first h bridge circuit done. I know there's some CI's for it, but I would like to test my dc motor on my on h bridge. So the low frequency. It would be a very weak RC car. Does it sound too low?

Comment: TIP120/122 can work with 100Hz without any problems, even 1kHz would work.

Comment: Great! I will rise to 1kHz so. But what calculations made this thought possible?

Comment: Reading the datasheet for TIP122 helps, and some hands-on experience.

Comment: It's not a FET it's a darlington-pair BJT